# Move group footer with at leat one record of group together to the next page

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using groups in JasperReports template. And sometimes the footer of group  is moved to the next page but header and all records are left on current page.

**How can I avoid this case and move at least one record to the next page with footer together?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use parameter minHeightToStartNewPage** and set it to value = DatailBandHeight + GroupHeaderBandHeight. If you have multiple groups try add group footer size, and column footer size. **This probably not work correctly, if components overflow**